# Sni multiple ssl on different virtualhosts Apache 2.4.10 (Debian)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, sni

Is it possible to set up multiple domains ssl on that apache version?

I have site A -> ssl certificate A
site B -> certificate B

then each file has a virtualhost like this, but it's not working: only site A has certificate applied correctly, browser says siteB has siteA certificate..

```
<Virtualhost *:8888>
    ServerName www.siteA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/siteA/
    RewriteEngine On

    <Directory /var/www/siteA/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    Loglevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/siteA-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/siteaA combined
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<Virtualhost *:443>
    ServerName siteA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/siteA/
    RewriteEngine On

    <Directory /var/www/siteA/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/siteA combined

# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =s
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/siteA/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/siteA/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

apachectl -S

```
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server siteA (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteA:24)
     port 443 namevhost siteA (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteA:24)
     port 443 namevhost siteB (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteB:8)
```

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Do I have sni enabled? AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:4

Comment: Is it possible that I cannot make this work cause I am using varnish+apache?

Answer (score 1):

**For using SSL in multiple websites under Apache2 server follow the steps**

File: `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName siteA.com
    ServerAlias www.siteA.com
    ServerAdmin admin@siteA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/siteA
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/siteA/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteA-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteA-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName siteB.com
    ServerAlias www.siteB.com
    ServerAdmin admin@siteB.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/siteB

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteB-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteB-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

File: `default-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@siteA.com
    ServerName www.siteA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/siteA

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/siteA_cf.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/siteA_cf.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/siteA_cf.ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName siteB.com
    ServerAlias www.siteB.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/siteB

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/siteB_cf.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/siteB_cf.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/siteB_cf.ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: [`SSLCertificateChainFile` has become obsolete](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile), use `SSLCACertificateFile` instead.

After creating these files, make sure your sites are enabled.

```
a2ensite 000-default.conf

a2ensite default-ssl.conf
```

Followed by a reload (or graceful restart)

```
service apache2 reload
```

[Reference](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)